# android - AndroidManifest referenced classes not validated

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I recently refactored my package structure for an Android project and moved a `BroadcastReceiver` class to a different package. However, I forgot to update the `receiver` tag's `android:name` field in the AndroidManifest.xml.

This `BroadcastReceiver` was used to send notifications to the client and this *serious* error simply meant that no notifications were sent. Unfortunately there is no compile time validation of this file or, it seems, any runtime error thrown to indicate a misconfiguration here.

Is there anything I can do from my side to validate these types of configurations? Perhaps this information can be accessed in a unit test and verified? Or, perhaps there is more verbose output I can configure to make sure error like this don't go unnoticed in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or, it seems, any runtime error thrown to indicate a misconfiguration here

A warning might have shown up in LogCat, but probably not, as having zero receivers for a broadcast is a perfectly normal condition.

> Is there anything I can do from my side to validate these types of configurations?

You can [file a feature request](http://b.android.com) to have Lint validate this portion of the manifest. Or, you can write your own script to analyze your source tree and manifest and include this as part of a customized Ant build script.

> Perhaps this information can be accessed in a unit test and verified?

You can use [`PackageManager` and `queryBroadcastReceivers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to confirm that the `Intent` you use for broadcasts will resolve to 1+ receivers.

Comment: A unit test validating PackageManager looks like the ticket. It's a shame there's nothing more standardized. I'll post my unit test when I have something working. Cheers.